# Parsing JSON and adding to a ListView

Tags: android, json, listview

I would like to update a different thread that I made with some code that I have written that is not working. I am trying to parse my information, which after sending a post request, looks like this [{"fromUser":"Andrew"},{"fromUser":"Jimmy"}]

I would then like to take those users, and add them to a list view.
Here is my code for sending the HTTPpost and then also my code for trying to parse and put it into the adapter.

```
String temp = "";
String arr[];
          HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(htmlUrl);

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", "Brock"));

            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                // writing response to log
                Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // writing exception to log
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // writing exception to log
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                JSONObject pendingUsers = new JSONObject("$myArray");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Read response to string
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
                System.out.print(result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }

            // Convert string to object
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                int count = jArray.length();

                for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    temp += json_data.getString("fromUser") + ":";
                }

                arr = temp.split(":");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "Updated";
    }
        public String[] getStringForAdapter()
        {
            return arr;
        }
}
```

Here is where I try to receive this and put it into my list

```
 HTTPSendPost postSender = new HTTPSendPost();
        postSender.Setup(500, 050, "tesT", htmlUrl);
        postSender.execute();

        String[] pendingRequestArray = postSender.getStringForAdapter();


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_friends, pendingRequestArray);

        pendingRequestsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I try it on my app, I don't get any results on the listView, any help would be appreciated. Sorry for the repost but I have a lot more information and code now. Next time I won't ask a question without the code I have tried. I get the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
 ComponentInfo{com.skyrealm.brockyy.findmypeepsapp
         /com.skyrealm.brockyy.findmypeepsapp.FriendsActivity}: 
 java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
```

Comment: What is that `storage` variable in the error?

Comment: Not sure, I don't have a storage variable which is why i'm confused with the error. @Konrad Krakowiak

Comment: I just edited your post I didn't change content. It is message which you pasted. Check in edit history

Comment: This particular exception ("storage == null") is thrown when the array parameter passed to ArrayAdapter(Context, int, T[]) is null. (To be more specific, it's thrown from Arrays.java when it tries to create a new ArrayList wrapped around your null array.)

Comment: Thank you! do you understand why I am getting this error or why it won't go into the List View, I believe it's because when I parse it and try to pass it to my activity that I need, it doesn't give any values and is Null, I'm just not sure why it doesn't pass through @KonradKrakowiak

Comment: Thank you KishanVaghela, thats exactly what I thought! Just not sure what is going wrong :(.

Comment: Go thorough this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/